# How can I convert From XML to Java and vice versa?

Tags: java, xml

How can I convert from XML to Java classes and vice versa?

Comment: Could you provide more details as to what your xml looks like and what you want the Java classes to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really convert from XML to Java because XML merely represents data which is (hopefully) structured in some way. One way to give XML structure is called XSD, and indeed it's possible to convert an XSD description into Java classes using a technology called [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) (Java Architecture for XML Binding).

Answer (score 4):

Use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/): Java Architecture for XML Binding.

Answer (score 2):

[JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), or [java.beans.XMLEncoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) / XMLDecoder all work for serialising and deserialising instanceso of Java classes.

Comment: -1 for XStream.  It's buggy, slow and poorly documented.

Comment: @skaffman - got any proof of that?  any links to such issues? we use it in prod with no problems...

Comment: @Ant: The poor documentation you can see for yourself.  The rest of it, I can say from having used it. It's my opinion.

Comment: your "opinion" cost me a -1 ;-)